# As3: Working with strings

Tags: string, actionscript-3, file, variables, text

I don't expect you to do all the work for me, but I need some information, since I'm not really familiar with this.

I've loaded file from URL and saved it's data into a string:

```
  function LoadData(e:Event):void
   {
   var datalanes:String = (e.target.data);
   }
```

The file contains certain data. Let's say it looks like this:

"

```
         Width: 10 Height: 15 Other: 4
```

"

Now I want the code to get all the data into a string. Like
var object.W = "Width" from file
var object.H = "Height" from file

Can anybody help me? I tried looking at adobe.help but this is not very well-understood by me.

Comment: Why dont you use a standardised format, like XML or JSON? Actionscript has very good parsers for both of these standards, it would save you a heck of a lot of effort

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use either JSON or XML but if you are to do it like this then take advantage of String parsing capability. For example String can be split easily. Given this:

```
width:50|||height:50|||other:4
```

You can easily get everything like this:

```
var data:String = "width:50|||height:50|||other:4";
var parts:Array = data.split("|||");
var width:Number = Number(String(parts[0]).split(":")[1]);
var height:Number = Number(String(parts[1]).split(":")[1]);
var other:Number = Number(String(parts[2]).split(":")[1]);
```

That's it.

Comment: Complicated. RegEx is a better solution. -1

Answer (score 1):

I agree with CyanAngel. Use a standardized format. JSON is extremely easy to parse in AS3.

```
var json:String = '{"width":10,"height":15,"other":4}';
var obj:Object = JSON.parse(json);
```

That's all you have to do and you'll have access to it through `obj.width`. If you *must* use the format you posted, you'll want to use `String#split` with some RegEx.

This is untested, but I believe this should do the job for you.

```
var s:String = 'Width: 10 Height: 15 Other: 4';
var a:Array = s.split(/(?<=\d)\s*(?=[a-zA-Z])/gm);
```

Then you could take it a step further and parse the data:

```
var obj:Object = {};
for (var i:int = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var key:String = a[i].match(/^\W*/)[0]; // this is an error prone way to do this. Should always check if index 0 exists
    var value:String = a[i].match(/(?<=:\s)\d*$/)[0];
    obj[key] = value;
}
```

Again, untested. Though I did make sure the RegEx was correct. Hopefully that at least helps point you in the right direction

Comment: Ok thanks guys! I didn't realize that using XML is sooo easy. I'm gonna stick with this.